# Xargs into second side of pipe?

Tags: pipe, xargs

I'm trying to do the following:

```
cat file1.txt | xargs -I{} "cat file2.txt | grep {}"
```

I'm expecting each line from file1 to be the value for grep at the end of the third pipe. It's not working as expected.

Is this because `-I{}` stops looking for things to replace once it hits the pipe? Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's because you need a shell to create a pipe or perform redirection. Note that `cat` is the command to concatenate, it makes little sense to use it just for one file.

```
cat file1.txt | xargs -I{} sh -c 'cat file2.txt | grep -e "$1"' sh {}
```

Do **not** do:

```
cat file1.txt | xargs -I{} sh -c 'cat file2.txt | grep -e {}'
```

as that would amount to a command injection vulnerability. The `{}` would be expanded in the code argument to `sh` so interpreted as shell code. For instance, if one the line of `file1.txt` was `$(reboot)` that would call `reboot`.

The `-e` (or you could also use `--`) is also important. Without it, you'd have problems with regexps starting with `-`.

You can simplify the above using redirections instead of `cat`:

```
< file1.txt xargs -I{} sh -c '< file2.txt grep -e "$1"' sh {}
```

Or simply pass the file names as argument to `grep` instead of using redirections in which case you can even drop the `sh`:

```
< file1.txt xargs -I{} grep -e {} file2.txt
```

You could also tell `grep` to look for all the regexps at once in a single invocation:

```
grep -f file1.txt file2.txt
```

Note however, that in that case, that's just one regexp for each line of `file1.txt`, there's none of the special quote processing done by `xargs`.

`xargs` by default considers its input as a list of blank (with some implementations only space and tab, on others any in the `[:blank:]` character class of the current locale) or newline separated words for which backslash and single and double quotes can be used to escape the separators (newline can only be escaped by backslash though) or each other.

For instance, on an input like:

```
 'a "b'\" "bar baz" x\
y
```

`xargs` without `-I{}` would pass `a "b"`, `bar baz` and `x<newline>y` to the command.

With `-I{}`, `xargs` gets one word per line but still does some extra processing. It ignores leading (but not trailing) blanks. Blanks are no longer considered as separators, but quote processing is still being done.

On the input above `xargs -I{}` would pass one `a "b" foo bar x<newline>y` argument to the command. Also note that one many systems, as required by POSIX, that won't work if words are more than 255 characters long. All in all, `xargs -I{}` is pretty useless.

If you want each line to be passed verbatim as argument to the command you could use GNU `xargs` `-d '\n'` extension:

```
< file1.txt xargs -d '\n' -n 1 grep file2.txt -e
```

(here relying on another extension of GNU `grep` that allows passing options after arguments (provided POSIXly correct is not in the environment) or portably:

```
sed "s/'/'\\\\\\''/g;s/.*/'&'/" file1.txt | xargs -n1 sh -c '
  for line do
    grep -e "$line" file2.txt
  done' sh
```

If you wanted each *word* in `file1.txt` (quotes still recognised) as opposed to each *line* to be looked for (which would also work around your trailing space issue if you have one word per line anyway), you can use `xargs -n1` alone instead of using `-I`:

```
< file1.txt xargs -n1 sh -c '
  for word do
    grep -e "$word" file2.txt
  done' sh
```

To strip leading and trailing blanks (but without the quote processing that `xargs` does), you could also do:

```
unset IFS # restore word splitting to its default
while read -r regexp; do
  grep -e "$regexp" file2.txt
done < file1.txt
```

Comment: When I used your commands they didn't work for me but the following modification did: cat file1.txt | xargs -I{} sh -c 'cat file2.txt | grep {}'

Comment: @Philip, see edit.

Comment: I appreciate knowing the vulnerability but I don't understand why the vulnerable command works but none of the other ones suggested do.

Comment: @Philip, in which way does it not work for you?

Comment: It doesn't return anything http://imgur.com/a/CV56w

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride, what do you see if you replace `sh -c` with `sh -xc`?

Comment: results: http://imgur.com/a/kuwBW

Comment: @Philip, I suspect if you replace `sh -xc` with `bash -xc`, you'd see `grep -e 'apples '`, that is that there are spaces at the end of the lines of `file1.txt` which `sh` (presumably `dash` as that looks like Ubuntu) doesn't show with `xtrace`.

Comment: After removing the extra spaces at the end of each line all your suggested answers worked. But yes for any future readers, extra space will break this.

Comment: @Philip, see edit for more alternatives.

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride No extra spaces/quotes/metachars wouldn't break it if you use the `-0` option: `< file1.txt tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -I{} grep -e {} file2.txt`

Comment: @Rakesh, or `xargs -d '\n'` if you're going to use GNUisms. But the assumption was that the quote handling was potentially desired here. After all, that's what `xargs` is for: parse lists of words.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas But the OP's first line says that & i quote: `I'm expecting each line from file1 to be the value for grep at the end of the third pipe.` So I was taking my cue from there.

Comment: @Rakesh, d'oh missed that. See edit.

Answer (score 8):

Depending on what you're trying to do, you may be better off skipping `xargs` entirely, and going with this solution instead:

```
grep -f file1.txt file2.txt
```

**This differs from your original command** (once we fix it as in Stéphane Chazelas's answer) as follows:

- Lines are printed in the order they appear in `file2.txt` regardless of which patterns they match.  In your command, all of the lines which match the first pattern are printed, then all of the lines which match the second, and so on.
- Lines which match more than one pattern are printed exactly once.  In your command, they are printed once for each pattern they match.
- Several flags can be used more easily, including both `-v` and `-c`.

The `-f` flag is [specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) and therefore reasonably portable.

Comment: Thanks @Stephane posted this option too but I appreciate the expanded explanation of how it differs.

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride: Good point.  Stéphane's answer is quite comprehensive, and I actually didn't spot that in my first read of it.

Comment: A great example of KISS and "less is more"

Comment: "Lines are printed in the order they appear in file2.txt regardless of which patterns they match" - this also means if you want to implement such custom sorting that can expressed by patterns it can be done very simply and fast using grep. Using grep to sort is not always intuitive.